# Adding to defaultdict keys using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, append, key

I have tried multiple different suggestions I found on other threads, but nothing seems to be working (yes I am new to programming lol).

I have the following code:

```
SysLength = defaultdict(list) #empty dictionary 
for x in SystemDict: 
    length = len(SystemDict[x]) #obtains length of each system
    SysLength[x].append(length) #adds system and length to the dictionary
SysMin = sorted(SysLength, key=SysLength.get) #sorts systems from smallest to largest 

emailDict = defaultdict(list) #empty dictionary

for x in SysMin: #cycles through lowest system first 
    for email in SystemDicto3[x]: #cycles through email in the lowest system
        emailDict[email] = 0 #adds email to dictionary and sets it equal to 0 

for x in SysMin: 
    for email in SystemDicto3[x]: 
        if emailDict[email] < 3: #if count is below 3, pass email through
            emailDict[email] += 1 #adds 1 to each email passed through
            SystemDictu4[x].append(email)
```

I am having an issue with this line:

```
SystemDictu4[x].append(email)
```

What I am looking to do is append 'email' to the key value 'x'. SystemDictu4 is a defaultdict with 1000's of entries under each key, and I need to add the email variable to those keys.

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Comment: It looks like `SystemDictu4[x]` is a dataframe, and you are trying to append a string to it. This will never work.

Comment: That's what I had believed as well but when I enter type(SystemDictu4) the output is collections.defaultdict, can it be changing to a df when i try to append to it?

Comment: how about `type(SystemDictu4[x])` ?

Comment: The output with that entered is pandas.core.series.Series why would it be changing to this? is there a way to append the way i need it to?

Comment: Well, first I'd investigate why you have a `pd.Series` in your dictionary when you're not expecting it. You can append to a series, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: please update your question with some sample data for `SystemDictu4`, `SystemDicto3` & `SystemDict` as they are created externally from the snippet you have shared here.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown was correct but as @jpp suggested me to, I reviewed how the SystemDictu4 dictionary was created. My original way of creating the dictionary was by using this snippet of code:

```
SystemDictu4 = defaultdict(list) #initializing dictionary
for item in SystemsList:
    SystemDictu4[item]=dfu4[dfu4[item]== 1.0]["Email"]
```

After some testing I learned that adding `.values.tolist()` to the end of the last line (after ['Email']), it works and does not change to a series. Thank you all for your assistance!